# node.js retrieve http csv file and load into mongoose

Tags: node.js, http, mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new to coding in general, so I apologize ahead of time if this question should be rather obvious.  Here's what I'm looking to do, and following that I'll post the code I've used so far.

I'm trying to get gzip'd csv rank data from a website and store it into a database, for a clan website that I'm working on developing.  Once I get this figured out, I'll need to grab the data once every 5 minutes.   The grabbing the csv data I've been able to accomplish, although it stores it into a text file and I need to store it into mongodb.

Here's my code:

```
var DB        =    require('../modules/db-settings.js');
var http      =    require('http');
var zlib      =    require('zlib');
var fs        =    require('fs');
var mongoose  =    require('mongoose');
var db          =   mongoose.createConnection(DB.host, DB.database, DB.port, {user: DB.user, pass: DB.password});

var request = http.get({ host: 'www.earthempires.com',
                     path: '/ranks_feed?apicode=myapicode',
                     port: 80,
                     headers: { 'accept-encoding': 'gzip' } });
request.on('response', function(response) {
  var output = fs.createWriteStream('./output');

  switch (response.headers['content-encoding']) {
    // or, just use zlib.createUnzip() to handle both cases
    case 'gzip':
      response.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(output);
      break;
    default:
      response.pipe(output);
      break;
  }
});

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  var rankSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serverid: Number,
    resetid: Number,
    rank: Number,
    countryNumber: Number,
    name: String,
    land: Number,
    networth: Number,
    tag: String,
    gov: String,
    gdi: Boolean,
    protection: Boolean,
    vacation: Boolean,
    alive: Boolean,
    deleted: Boolean
  })
});
```

Here's an example of what the csv will look like(first 5 lines of file):

```
9,386,1,451,Super Kancheong Style,22586,318793803,LaF,D,1,0,0,1,0
9,386,2,119,Storm of Swords,25365,293053897,LaF,D,1,0,0,1,0
9,386,3,33,eug gave it to mak gangnam style,43501,212637806,LaF,H,1,0,0,1,0
9,386,4,128,Justpickupgirlsdotcom,22628,201606479,LaF,H,1,0,0,1,0
9,386,5,300,One and Done,22100,196130870,LaF,H,1,0,0,1,0
```

Comment: My question is how do I get that csv data into mongodb?  I'm not sure on where I should look next or what to do next.  I'm sorta just stuck.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. You'd parse the CSV into objects that follow `rankSchema` and then insert them into your collection using the Mongoose APIs.  You're going to have to take the time to learn about how to do those steps as there aren't canned solutions.

Comment: Alright, well that's sorta what I needed to know.  I wasn't sure if what I'm looking for is something that was common or not.  I appreciate your kindness and your advice.  Thank you.   Should I just delete this question?

Comment: Up to you.  If you found it useful someone else might as well.

Comment: If you write some code to parse the CSV into a model that you insert using mongoose, feel free to answer your own question so anyone else stumbling here will see how you did it.

Comment: @Chad:  Whenever I figure it out, I sure will.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope it's not too late to help, but here's what I'd do:

1. Request the CSV formatted data and store it in memory or a file.
2. Parse the CSV data to convert each row into an object.
3. For each object, use `Model.create()` to create your new entry.

First, you need to create a model from your Schema:

```
var Rank = db.model('Rank', rankSchema);
```

Then you can parse your block of CSV text (whether you read it from a file or do it directly after your request is up to you.) I created my own bogus `data` variable since I don't have access to the api, but as long as your data is a newline delimited block of CSV text this should work:

```
/* Data is just a block of CSV formatted text. This can be read from a file                                                                                                  
   or retrieved right in the response. */                                                                                                                                    
var data = '' +                                                                                                                                                              
    '9,386,1,451,Super Kancheong Style,22586,318793803,LaF,D,1,0,0,1,0\n' +                                                                                                  
    '9,386,2,119,Storm of Swords,25365,293053897,LaF,D,1,0,0,1,0\n' +                                                                                                        
    '9,386,3,33,eug gave it to mak gangnam style,43501,212637806,LaF,H,1,0,0,1,0\n' +                                                                                        
    '9,386,4,128,Justpickupgirlsdotcom,22628,201606479,LaF,H,1,0,0,1,0\n' +                                                                                                  
    '9,386,5,300,One and Done,22100,196130870,LaF,H,1,0,0,1,0\n';                                                                                                            

data = data.split('\n');                                                                                                                                                     

data.forEach(function(line) {                                                                                                                                                
    line = line.split(',');   

    if (line.length != 14)
        return;                                                                                                                                               

    /* Create an object representation of our CSV data. */                                                                                                                   
    var new_rank = {                                                                                                                                                         
        serverid: line[0],                                                                                                                                                   
        resetid: line[1],                                                                                                                                                    
        rank: line[2],                                                                                                                                                       
        countryNumber: line[3],                                                                                                                                              
        name: line[4],                                                                                                                                                       
        land: line[5],                                                                                                                                                       
        networth: line[6],                                                                                                                                                   
        tag: line[7],                                                                                                                                                        
        gov: line[8],                                                                                                                                                        
        gdi: line[9],                                                                                                                                                        
        protection: line[10],                                                                                                                                                
        vacation: line[11],                                                                                                                                                  
        alive: line[12],                                                                                                                                                     
        deleted: line[13]                                                                                                                                                    
    };                                                                                                                                                                       

    /* Store the new entry in MongoDB. */                                                                                                                                    
    Rank.create(new_rank, function(err, rank) {                                                                                                                            
        console.log('Created new rank!', rank);                                                                                                                              
    });                                                                                                                                                                      
});
```

You could put this in a script and run it every 5-minutes using a cron job. On my Mac, I'd edit my cron file with `crontab -e`, and I'd setup a job with a line like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/node /path/to/script.js > /dev/null
```

Comment: Sorry for just now getting back to this.  Its not too late, this is awesome--thanks for your help.  I'll accept this answer as its the best i've seen.  For some reason, it didn't occur to me to do split the lines myself and foreach through it.  I've been looking and messing with a bunch of NPM packages that all needed tinkering with.  Accepting the answer, its very much appreciated.  The /* Store the new entry in MongoDB. */  is particularly helpful.  I know I've seen examples of it in api docs and other pieces, but I wasn't quite able to grasp it.  Thank you.